# How I can get the current price of my app in play store to each location in order to show in a textView

Tags: java, android, localization, google-play, currency

I'm trying to implement a button on my free app that lead to my pro app version page, I want to do something like this: a dialog that says, for example, "Buy the pro version, it's just (price here)."

Ok, here is my problem, how I get the current price (to each country) of my app on google play, I mean, in order to show the correct price to user (in their currency), the same price that she/he will see when open the google play page in your location. I saw some apps that did this, for example R$ 2,99 (to real), or $1.90 to dollar... How it's possible?

Comment: Considering currency rates fluctuate, you have to use some currency conversion API.

Answer (score 3):

There [is a method](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts) for that in the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/). 
There's also [a convenient Java client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/androidpublisher/v1) that should be usable from Android. 
There's some [setup](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) involved of course, mainly authentication stuff. 
The API is imho mainly meant to manage apps from a Java backend, and given the proper permissions, you cannot only 'read' but also 'write' (e.g. change the price of your in-app-products), so use it wisely ;)

Comment: Thanks, but actually I forgot to say that my apps (pro and free) have different package names, (like - com.example.lite and com.example.pro), then I need to get price of pro app inside the code of lite one. Has a way I can do that?

Comment: @Anita That shouldn't be a problem, via the API you can have access to any apps within your account, just provide the proper package name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new on this, there is any practical example, I found this one Trivial Drive on github, but it's about items of same app, what I have to change to refer other app? Like I said I'm new... :) Thanks

Comment: Any sample project on Github or somewhere ?